# Near Zero Variance variables

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I'm using a subset of the `MNIST` dataset (http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/). The task is to predict the digit using the explanatory variables, which are from pixel 1 to pixel 255 (RGB scale) and two of the methods that I've been taught to use is logistic regression and linear discriminant analysis for classification problems.

However when I run the logistic regression command, I get the following error message:

`glm.fit: algorithm did not convergeglm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred`

and when I run the `lda` command, I get the following error message:

`Error in lda.default(x, grouping, ...) : 
variables  11  12  27  28  29  30  31 124 125 420 549 597 appear to be constant within groups`

I've done some Googling and results seem to suggest that this is related ro "near zero variance" predictors (https://www.r-bloggers.com/near-zero-variance-predictors-should-we-remove-them/) (which would make sense, given how the data looks).

However, when I use the `nearZeroVar` function from the `caret` package, all x variables are classified as "near zero variance". Is there any possible way I can fix this problem so that I can run the logistic and LDA models?

Comment: Have you missed to code factors as factors and not numeric ??

Comment: I will have a look at that. I think I coded the response variable as a factor variable.